# How do I conditionally set the destination object to null using automapper

Tags: c#, automapper

I am trying to do something like this:

```
AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<UrlPickerState, Link>()
        .ForMember(m=>m.OpenInNewWindow,map=>map.MapFrom(s=>s.NewWindow))
        .AfterMap((picker, link) => link = !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(link.Url)?link:null) ;

var pickerState = new UrlPickerState();
var linkOutput = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<Link>(pickerState);
```

However, the assigned value of `link` is not used in any execution path.
I would like linkOutput to be null, but it is not.
How would I make the destination object null?

Details of objects involved:

```
public class Link
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public bool OpenInNewWindow { get; set; }
}

public class UrlPickerState
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public bool NewWindow { get; set; }
    //.... etc
}
```

Here's a fiddle: http://dotnetfiddle.net/hy2nIa

Comment: ..what part of the above doesn't work? Expand the `AfterMap` method out and put a breakpoint on there.

Comment: It gets called. However the result of the assignment is not persisted beyond the scope of the method (from what I can see)

Comment: Does your source object (UrlPickerState) contain a Url property?  It would help if you showed the layout of UrlPickerState and Link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I created the following extension method to solve this problem.

```
public static IMappingExpression<TSource, TDestination> PreCondition<TSource, TDestination>(
   this IMappingExpression<TSource, TDestination> mapping
 , Func<TSource, bool> condition
)
   where TDestination : new()
{
   // This will configure the mapping to return null if the source object condition fails
   mapping.ConstructUsing(
      src => condition(src)
         ? new TDestination()
         : default(TDestination)
   );

   // This will configure the mapping to ignore all member mappings to the null destination object
   mapping.ForAllMembers(opt => opt.PreCondition(condition));

   return mapping;
}
```

For the case in question, it can be used like this:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<UrlPickerState, Link>()
      .ForMember(dest => dest.OpenInNewWindow, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.NewWindow))
      .PreCondition(src => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(src.Url));
```

Now, if the condition fails, the mapper will return null; otherwise, it will return the mapped object.

Comment: awesome, I put it in the fiddle here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Ra1xKf works great, thanks.

Answer (score 7):

This is the solution I used in the end, it was a bit more manual internally, but does not require any extra plumbing.

If anyone has a more elegant solution, it would be appreciated.

```
config.CreateMap<UrlPickerState, Link>()
            .ConvertUsing(arg =>
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(arg.Url))
                {
                    return null;
                }
                return new Link()
                {
                    Url = arg.Url,
                    OpenInNewWindow = arg.NewWindow,
                    Title = arg.Title,
                };
            });
```

Comment: This one worked for my situation as well. I had been using ConstructUsing with the exact same body and that was causing an exception to be thrown.

Answer (score 1):

I think that will have to be done outside the mapping.  Since AutoMapper requires an *instance* to map to, setting the destination to `null` seems like it should go outside the mapping.

I would instead do something like:

```
AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<UrlPickerState, Link>()
        .ForMember(m=>m.OpenInNewWindow,map=>map.MapFrom(s=>s.NewWindow));

var pickerState = new UrlPickerState();
Link linkOutput = null;
if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(pickerState.Url))  // or whatever condition is appropriate
    linkOutput = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<Link>(pickerState);
```

Comment: Works, however note: I'm looking to reduce the plumbing, since links are all over my view models.

Comment: You can write a reusable function to do that. You can have an IHasLink interface and map from that. AM considers the runtime type of the source object, so that should work.