# AutoMapper set destination to null on condition of source property

Tags: c#, automapper

I'm mapping between two objects and based on a condition of the source I would like the destination to be null.

For example, here are the classes:

```
public class Foo
{
    public int Code { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

}

public class Bar
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
}
```

And my map:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Foo, Bar>()
            .AfterMap((s, d) => { if (s.Code != 0) d = null; });
```

But it seems to ignore the AfterMap. Bar is initialised although with all default properties.

How can I get the mapper to return null based on Code not being equal to 0?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I conditionally set the destination object to null using automapper](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23209101/how-do-i-conditionally-set-the-destination-object-to-null-using-automapper)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible way is -

```
class Converter : TypeConverter<Foo, Bar>
{
    protected override Bar ConvertCore(Foo source)
    {
        if (source.Code != 0)
            return null;
        return new Bar();
    }
}


static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Mapper.CreateMap<Foo, Bar>()
            .ConvertUsing<Converter>();


        var bar = Mapper.Map<Bar>(new Foo
        {
            Code = 1
        });
        //bar == null true
    }
```

Comment: Do I have to manually add the mappings I want in the TypeConverter or can I get it to automatically map after?

Comment: I'm afraid, Yes. Because now you're responsible for creation of the destination type.

Answer (score 0):

I created the following extension method to solve this problem.

```
public static IMappingExpression<TSource, TDestination> PreCondition<TSource, TDestination>(
   this IMappingExpression<TSource, TDestination> mapping
 , Func<TSource, bool> condition
)
   where TDestination : new()
{
   // This will configure the mapping to return null if the source object condition fails
   mapping.ConstructUsing(
      src => condition(src)
         ? new TDestination()
         : default(TDestination)
   );

   // This will configure the mapping to ignore all member mappings to the null destination object
   mapping.ForAllMembers(opt => opt.PreCondition(condition));

   return mapping;
}
```

For the case in question, it can be used like this:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Foo, Bar>()
      .PreCondition(src => src.Code == 0);
```

Now, if the condition fails, the mapper will return null; otherwise, it will return the mapped object.

Answer (score -1):

I prefer custom value resolvers. Here is my take...

```
public class CustomValueResolver : IValueResolver<Foo, Bar, string>
{
    public string Resolve(Foo source, Bar destination, string destMember, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        return source.Code != 0 ? null : "asd";
    }
}

public class YourProfile : Profile
{
    public YourProfile()
    {
        this.CreateMap<Foo, Bar>()
            .ForMember(dst => dst.Name, opt => opt.MapFrom<CustomValueResolver>())
            // ... 
            ;

    }
}
```

Comment: The question is about setting the entire destination to null, not a specific member - so while valid code it doesn't solve the problem discussed.