# Set parental objects to null instead of initializing them in AutoMapper if source is null

Tags: c#, automapper

#### Situation overview

AutoMapper provides functionality to set Collections to null if no value was assigned for it, I am looking for a similar thing but objects.

```
new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
{
   cfg.AllowNullCollections = true;
   cfg.AddProfile(new CustomMapper());
});
```

Let's say I have a simple DTO

```
public class RequestModel
{
   public string? Header { get; set; }
}
```

Which should map to InnerObject's Header property.

```
public class Document
{
   public InnerObject? InnerObject { get; set; }
}

public class InnerObject{
{
  public string? Header { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see fields are nullables which means that DTO's Header may be null.

1. When Header is not null - AutoMapper automatically creates dependant objects (InnerObject) and assigns correct value
2. When Header is null - AutoMapper still creates instance even though no value will be assigned to InnerObject.Header

```
CreateMap<RequestModel, Document>()
                .ForPath(
                    dest => dest.InnerObject.Header,
                    opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.Header));
```

#### Question

The question is how to configure AutoMapper not to initialize parental objects (InnerObject in our case) if children objects (Header in our case) is null.

#### Json example

Expected:

```
"innerObject": null
```

Actual

```
"innerObject": {
    "header": null
}
```

#### Similar cases

1. Solution provided in accepted answer is not effective as it requires manual destination object creation. So if there are 100 different properties, it would be needed to write custom converts for them. Answer was posted in 2015, maybe AutoMapper introduced any updates. [AutoMapper set destination to null on condition of source property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34288574/automapper-set-destination-to-null-on-condition-of-source-property)
2. Extension method answer suggested in following thread might be a remedy for simple objects, but it would not work with complex objects when there is a need to create 3 parental objects (Ex. ParentalComplexObject.ChildrenComplexObject1.ChildrenComplexObject2.SimpleString) [How do I conditionally set the destination object to null using automapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23209101/how-do-i-conditionally-set-the-destination-object-to-null-using-automapper)

#### Potential workaround

Speaking of potential workaround, some kind of utility service might be introduced to perform cleanup setting objects to null if its inner children (complex objects or properties) are null, however IMO it is not elegant solution. [Set Object null if all its properties are null in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53745133/set-object-null-if-all-its-properties-are-null-in-c-sharp)

Comment: This was discussed many times before. Just don't use `ForPath`.

Comment: I use ```ForPath``` because it allows me to map nested objects without worrying about parental object initialization. ```ForMember``` requires all objects to be initialized before mapping and that is not the desired action to do as I am working with nullables (unless I am missing something important)

Comment: That doesn't sound right :) Avoid `ForPath` and you avoid the problem.

Comment: Pretty much I was following exception message when I used ForMember: ```must resolve to top-level member and not any child object's properties. You can use ForPath, a custom resolver on the child type or the AfterMap option instead```

Comment: I am definitely missing something  I have tried fixing this error using reverse map ```CreateMap<Document, RequestModel>().ForMember(d => d.Header, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.InnerObject .Header)).ReverseMap();``` but the behavior is the same. It maps correctly, but when RequestModel.Header property is null, InnerObject is still initialized (not assigned to null) even if its Header property is null.

Comment: You're going around in circles. Check [the execution plan](https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Understanding-your-mapping.html). Avoid `ReverseMap` and create the maps explicitly. Again, all this was discussed _many_ times before.

Comment: Thanks, I have checked the execution plan and pretty much it just initializes complex object if it is null, goes deeper and there is no way to cancel that -  ```.If ($typeMapDestination.InnerObject== null) {
                                $typeMapDestination.InnerObject = .New ProjectNamespace.Mappings.Temporary.InnerObject()
                            } ```. Anyways, thank you for your input :)  I'll figure out workaround as this consumed quite a bit of time

Answer (score 0):

You can use `AfterMap()` like this:

```cs
CreateMap<RequestModel, Document>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.InnerObject, opt => opt.Ignore())
    .AfterMap((src, dest) => {
        if (src.Header != null)
        {
            dest.InnerObject = new InnerObject();
            dest.InnerObject.Header = src.Header;
        }
    });
```